# Custom UICollectionReusableView elements not shown

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

UICollectionView Header part.

```
class HeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_HeaderText: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

Setting value to header.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                    at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView", for: indexPath)

    headerView.lbl_HeaderText = "Some Text"
    return headerView

}
}
```

`lbl_HeaderText` do not shows for subclass link to headerView links to only `UICollectionReusableView` does not show or have "`HeaderView`" property

Answer (score 0):

The API requires that you register the supplementary view with

```
func register(AnyClass?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: String, withReuseIdentifier: String)
```

or

```
func register(UINib?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: String, withReuseIdentifier: String)
```